# Additional virtual/navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following model:

```
public class Useraccount
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

The tasks collection is filled by the entity framework via the task entity. This is working without problems. 
Now I'd like to have an additional virtual property so the class would look like this:

```
public class Useraccount
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Task> FinishedTasks { get; set; }
}
```

The FinishedTasks property is the same like Tasks, but it only has tasks which are finished (which have the statusId = 1 for example).
Is it possible to do that with the EF? How?

Comment: Please don't include "Thanks." in your question. It is useless noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the  property like this:

```
public class Useraccount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Task> FinishedTasks
    {
        get
        {
            return Tasks.Where(t => t.Finished);
        }
    }
}
```

`NotMapped` attribute tells the EF that this property is not mapped to a database column (see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591583) for more information).

There is no need to make it virtual (unless you exactly know why) because EF is not going to override it. Also the `set` accessor should not be present, because it is actually a calculated property.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try that this afternoon.